# If $P$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, then, prove that $P=H/n\Bbb Z$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Tags: group-theory

If $P$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, then, prove that $P=H/n\Bbb Z$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.(i.e $P$ has the form $H/n\Bbb Z$)

I dont have a clue on how to procced. I dont get how to prove this at all. Any hints/help will be much appreciated? This fact seems trivial, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much more general result (which will give you a feel of how "trivial" the statement is).

Let $G,M$ be any groups and $\phi:G\to M$ a surjective group homomorphism. Suppose $N$ is a subgroup of $M$. Then $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a subgroup of $G$ whose image by $\phi$ is $N$.

Now if you identify the group homomorphism that sends $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, you should see how it's a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  the subgroups of a cyclic group $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ are cyclic,  of order dividing $n$.

Or $P\cong\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z,$ where $d\mid n.$

So, let $H=(n/d)\Bbb Z$.  Then $$H/n\Bbb Z\cong P.$$

Note that $n\Bbb Z\le n/d\Bbb Z\le\Bbb Z$, so that this checks out with the correspondence theorem.